# Azure Synapse Analytics - ingestion process and locking

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse, azure-sql-server

I have a 5TB SQL Server database on-premise I would like to ingest into Azure Synapse Analytics. My questions:

- what happens when data is ingested?
- will there be a lock on the source database when ingestion is running?
- can other application still use the database while ingestion is running?

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a thing such as database locking in this sense.  Read locks will be acquired at row, page or table level depending on the type of queries you are running to extract data, and even this is a simplified explanation (See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/sql-server-locks-object?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Locks%20are%20held%20on%20SQL,until%20the%20lock%20is%20released.) for more details for example).  This will allow other applications to use the database while ingestion is running.  This **may** generate locking (even blocking) if your application is doing update / insert / delete operations at the same time.  Other readers should **not** be blocked.

All of this depends on a number of things such as: the length of the read operation, the transaction isolation level of the given operation, the status of read committed snapshot on your database etc so it's not really a 'yes' or 'no' answer.

My observation would be that 5TB is a large db to consume in this manner.  Is it volatile?  eg are records changing while it's being read?

If so, you might consider an alternative approach, eg take a database back up, which is fixed at a point in time, restore it to a VM in the cloud and extract from there.  That would be one way of ensuring uninterrupted access and having a consistent snapshot at a specific point in time.  If you have a stricter requirement around this consistency you should consider other options such as marking a database as read-only (during the extract) or remove all write access.

It kind of depends on how volatile your db is and whether or not that matters for your process.

Comment: Any views on this one @DavidBrowne-Microsoft?  It seems a bit of a general question but I've tried to give a bit of advice.